# Fastest way to convert a very large SQL Server table

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2012

We are redesigning a very large (~100Gb, partitioned) table in SQL Server 2012.

For that we need to convert data from the old (existing) table into the newly designed table on the production server. The new table is also partitioned. Rows are only appended to the table.

The problem is a lot of users work on this server, and we can do this conversion process only in chunks and when the server is not under heavy load (a couple of hours a day).

I wonder if there is a better & faster way?

This time we will finish the conversion process in a few days (and then switch our application to use the new table), but what would we do if the table was 1Tb? Or 10Tb?

PS. More details on the current process:
The tables are partitioned based on the CloseOfBusinessDate column (DATE). Currently we run this query when the server is under low load:

```
INSERT INTO
  NewTable
...
SELECT ... FROM
  OldTable -- this SELECT involves xml parsing and CROSS APPLY
WHERE
  CloseOfBusinessDate = @currentlyMigratingDate
```

Every day about 1M rows from the old table gets converted into 200M rows in the new table.
When we finish the conversion process we will simply update our application to use NewTable.

Comment: It would depend on the initial schema and the target schema.  Are you converting one table to many tables?  Are you changing the partitioning scheme?  Is the partitioning manual or automated?  Are rows only appended to the table, or are they updated and/or deleted too?  Can one table be made to "appear as" the other table by wrapping it in a view?  Your question is too broad at present, give specific details on the changes you are making and we can give specific suggestions.

Comment: Using SP_Rename could work. Name the existing table something with _OLD after it, change your new table to the production name, and make sure all FK's are accounted for.

Comment: @MatBailie, I have updated my question. We're converting one table to one table. The table can be made to "appear as" the other table by wrapping it in a view, but that view would work slowly, because the conversion is not trivial.

Comment: "I wonder if there is a better & faster way". Possibly. As we have no idea what your existing code looks like how would we know?

Comment: If there are no UPDATEs or DELETEs, only INSERTs to the end of the table, then migrating one partition at a time (or part of a partition) should mean that your migration activity doesn't block any other user processes?  Without more specific details this is like asking "what's the best way to repair my car if I still need it for work?" but not telling us how you use it for work, what repairs you're doing, etc, etc...

Comment: @MartinSmith, I've updated the question.

Comment: Still not many details. Is the execution plan for the SELECT optimised? Are you getting minimal logging on the insert? Are the files pre grown to sufficient capacity?

Comment: From your sample code, it seems you do not care about the potential changes to your old (i.e. current) table, I mean that during or after your insert .. select ..., there may be data changes (like new rows, modified rows, deleted rows), how do you handle this data change scenario?

Comment: @jyao - I already asked that, and the OP answered it in an edit : `Rows are only appended to the table.`

Comment: @MartinSmith, thank you very much for your comment. Honestly, I didn't have all the details myself. But your question about whether the select query is optimized made me check that query and turns out it is very slow and inefficient. I gave more details in the answer, but you can post your answer suggesting to check the select query and I will accept it as solution.

Answer (score 1):

Everybody, who took time to read the question and tried to help me, I'm sorry, I didn't have enough details myself. Turns out the query that selects data from the old table and converts it, is VERY slow (thanks to @Martin Smith I've decided to check the SELECT query). The query involves parsing xml & uses cross apply. I think the better way in our case would be to write a small application that would simply load data from the old table for each day, convert it in memory and then use Bulk Copy to insert into the new table.